# Async tast not working as it should

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I am trying to do webservice async so ui can respond and websevice call is done in background, but since i am little inexpirienced with async stuff i need little help.
Here is my code:

Inside my action result i have call to method which have asyinc stuff in it

```
 public ActionResult SavePackage(string ParcelNumber)
{
/////some other stuff
 SaveAsync(ParcelNumber);
}
 And
```

then i have async method :

```
 public async Task SaveAsync(string ParcelNumber)
        {
            await api.RegisterPackage(ParcelNumber);
        }
```

Which calls api:

```
  public async Task RegisterPackage(string ParcelNumber)
        {
            var rk = "some api http";

            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(rk) as HttpWebRequest;
           request.Headers.Add("cache-control", "no-cache");
          request.Method = "POST";
          request.ContentType = "application/json";

            string data = "{\n   \"ParcelNumber\": \"" + ParcelNumber+ "\"}";
            byte[] dataStream = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
            Stream newStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            // Send the data.
            newStream.Write(dataStream, 0, dataStream.Length);
            newStream.Close();

            Task<WebResponse> getResponseTask = Task<WebResponse>.Factory.FromAsync(request.BeginGetResponse, request.EndGetResponse, null);

            await getResponseTask.ContinueWith(getResponseAntecedent =>
             {
                 WebResponse webResponse = getResponseAntecedent.Result;

                 using (var reader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                 {
                     string error = reader.ReadToEnd();
                     //TODO: use JSON.net to parse this string and look at the error message
                     var myDeserializedObjList3 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObjectAtt>(error);

                     var isValid = myDeserializedObjList3.IsValid;
                     var ModelErrors = myDeserializedObjList3.ModelErrors;
                     var ValidationErrors = myDeserializedObjList3.ValidationErrors;
                 }
             });
        }
```

My problem is that the above code is still waiting for response to finish (and that can take about 20 second), and i would like if possible when i call the api i could go back to my ui and let ppl do their stuff while api is proccessed in background.

Anybody have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

As I describe on my blog, [`async` does not change the HTTP protocol](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/08/async-doesnt-change-http-protocol.html).

First, the *best* solution to your problem is to not change your ASP.NET action method at all. Instead, have the actual *UI* application issue the call asynchronously. If your UI app is a .NET app, then it can use `async`/`await`; if it's a web app (i.e., JavaScript), then it can use an AJAX call. Another good option is to introduce SignalR, which allows the server to signal when the work is done.

If you *really* want to run ASP.NET code outside of a request (which is never recommended), then you can use one of the techniques I describe on my blog for [ASP.NET fire-and-forget](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html).

Comment: My app is a web app and i will try with your approach.